# Oracle SQL Missing Expression/Syntax Error

Tags: sql, oracle, count, having

So basically my issue is I have the following query and I'm getting an error saying there's a syntax error but I can work out what. I'm wondering whether I can't using **HAVING COUNT()** in a subquery.

```
SELECT FIELDNUM
FROM INTEREST 
GROUP BY FIELDNUM
HAVING COUNT(ACNUM) >= ALL(SELECT FIELDNUM
                       FROM INTEREST
                       HAVING COUNT(ACNUM));
```

The syntax error shows up at the last 2 closing parenthesis, i.e.
HAVING COUNT( ACNUM **))**;

The outcome I am trying to get is the field (FIELDNUM) with the most academics(ACNUMS) interested in it but I'm not allowed to use MAX or ROWNUM.

The interest table has the attributes FIELDNUM, ACNUM, and DESCRIPTION.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Why would you be comparing a count result to `fieldnum`.  It is really not possible to help without knowing what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Editted with more info.

Answer (score 1):

The query would at least make sense if it were structured as:

```
SELECT FIELDNUM
FROM INTEREST 
GROUP BY FIELDNUM
HAVING COUNT(ACNUM) >= ALL (SELECT COUNT(ACNUM)
                            FROM INTEREST
                            GROUP BY FIELDNUM
                           );
```

This is not how I would recommend writing the logic to get the `fieldnum`s that occur the most times in the table, but it is a valid method.

Comment: That's the outcome I was looking for, know it's not the best way of doing it but I'm trying to do it without using MAX or ROWNUM.